# Plot bar graph using group by

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I made an dataframe using

```
 output=  {(0, 0): 50.0, (0, 1): 100.0, (0, 2): 100.0, (0, 3): 100.0, 
    (1, 0): 0, (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 200.0, (1, 3): 75.0, 
    (2, 0): 0, (2, 1): 150.0, (2, 2): 150.0, (2, 3): 0, 
    (3, 0): 500.0, (3, 1): 500.0, (3, 2): 500.0, (3, 3): 500.0, 
    (4, 0): 0, (4, 1): 0, (4, 2): 5550.0, (4, 3):0 }

value=[aa,bb,cc,dd]
name=[a,b,c,d,e]

s=pd.Series(output).unstack()
s.columns = value
s.index = name
pd.set_option("display.width", 170)
print(s)

    aa        bb     cc     dd
a   50.0    100.0   100.0   100.0
b   0         0     200.0   75.0
c   0       150.0   150.0    0
d   500.0   500.0   500.0   500.0
e   0         0     5500.0   0
```

I need to get a bar graph,

```
x-Axis->>All labels of
aa (With in this group by a,b,c,d,e),bb(With in this group by a,b,c,d,e),cc(With in this group by a,b,c,d,e),dd(With in this group by a,b,c,d,e),ee(With in this group by a,b,c,d,e)
```

y-Axis->>Values

Could you advise how I can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw a **bar** plot from a DataFrame, then the general rule
of labelling is that:

- **x** labels are names of each row,
- **legend** labels are from each column,
- **y** labels are numeric, allowing to read the height of each bar.

As you wrote that you want *aa*, *bb*, *cc*, ... (i.e. **column** names)
as x labels, the bar plot should be generated from a **transposition**
of your DataFrame.

One way to generate it is:

```
s.T.plot.bar(rot=0);
```

Note the terminating `;` to block a printout concerning details of
the created picture object (something like
`<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at ...>`).

I added *rot=0* parameter to have x labels without rotation, as the
default rotation is 90 (degrees).

For your data, slightly changed to get not very much different heights
of bars, I got:

[image]

(I changed *5500.0* to *855*, otherwise one bar would be very high
and all other very low.)

Comment: This is perfect.Your explanation is crystal clear.I am new to python.Is there any good site that we can have this kind of clear instruction for a beginner

Comment: As far as plotting in Python is concerned, one good site is a Pyplot tutorial
at https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html
Formally, it is another module (*pyplot* not *pandas*), but *pandas* uses just it for plotting. Another source of knowledge is just StackOverflow.

Comment: This is Fantastic @Valdi_Bo.I will go through this.